# Django 1.4.5 - Failed to install index for WorldBorder model

Tags: mysql, django, geospatial

Since I upgraded to Django 1.4.5 and dropped and recreated a `MySQL 5.5.8` database, I get this error message upon `./manage syncdb`

```
Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Failed to install index for my_app.WorldBorder model: 
   (1464, "The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes")
```

Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',    
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.gis', <---- here
    'pipeline',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'my_app',  
    'south',  
    'modeltranslation',
    'djcelery',
)
```

But I have already downloaded and compiled the Geos and it always worked so far:

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.3.0.tar.bz2
tar xjf geos-3.3.0.tar.bz2
auto-apt run ./configure
make -j4
sudo checkinstall
sudo ldconfig
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use Postgresql with PostGIS extension.

Comment: Seriously? I have to change my whole database because this feature doesn't work? Sure...

Comment: I didn't say you had to, but mysql has well documented spatial limitations compared with PostGRE: http://openlife.cc/blogs/2012/august/comparing-open-source-gis-implementations. In fact,the first section on geodjango.org discussing database support (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/) is titled 'Mysql spatial limitations'. I switched to PostGRE after having difficulty with spatial queries using Mysql, and so that is why I posted it as a recommendation to you. Django makes it easy to switch, but it is your call in the end. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately I am using RDS and there is no support for the Postgres.  You may post this as an answer and I tick it off. I have to leave with that. What a shame though. Django is too focused on one database.

Answer (score 1):

Creating spatial indexes returns an error if the data base type is not myisam:

ERROR 1464 (HY000): The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes

You can change the database type to myisam and this example will work by doing the following:

```
alter table geom engine=myisam;
```

For reference, check the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html